# Convert .CSV file to point feature class using python 2.7

Tags: python, csv, python-2.7

I have a .CSV file with 75 columns and almost 4000 rows. I need to create a shapefile (point) for the entire .CSV file, with each column as a field. All 75 columns need to be brought over to the new shapefile, with each column representing a field.

There seems to a good amount on this topic already, but everything I can find addresses .csv files with a small number of columns.

https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/17590/why-is-an-extra-field-necessary-when-creating-point-shapefile-from-csv-files-in

https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/35593/using-the-python-shape-library-pyshp-how-to-convert-csv-file-to-shp

This script looks close to what I need to accomplish, but again it adds a field for every column in the .CSV, which in this example there are three fields; DATE, LAT, LON.

```
import arcpy, csv
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

#Set variables
arcpy.env.workspace = "C:\\GIS\\StackEx\\"
outFolder = arcpy.env.workspace
pointFC = "art2.shp"
coordSys = "C:\\Program Files\\ArcGIS\\Desktop10.0\\Coordinate Systems" + \
           "\\Geographic Coordinate Systems\\World\\WGS 1984.prj"
csvFile = "C:\\GIS\\StackEx\\chicken.csv"
fieldName = "DATE1"

#Create shapefile and add field
arcpy.CreateFeatureclass_management(outFolder, pointFC, "POINT", "", "", "", coordSys)
arcpy.AddField_management(pointFC, fieldName, "TEXT","","", 10)

gpsTrack = open(csvFile, "r")

headerLine = gpsTrack.readline()
#print headerLine
#I updated valueList to remove the '\n'
valueList = headerLine.strip().split(",")
print valueList
latValueIndex = valueList.index("LAT")
lonValueIndex = valueList.index("LON")
dateValueIndex = valueList.index("DATE")

# Read each line in csv file
cursor = arcpy.InsertCursor(pointFC)
for point in gpsTrack.readlines():

   segmentedPoint = point.split(",")
   # Get the lat/lon values of the current reading                    
   latValue = segmentedPoint[latValueIndex]
   lonValue = segmentedPoint[lonValueIndex]
   dateValue = segmentedPoint[dateValueIndex]
   vertex = arcpy.CreateObject("Point")
   vertex.X = lonValue
   vertex.Y = latValue
   feature = cursor.newRow()
   feature.shape = vertex
   feature.DATE1 = dateValue
   cursor.insertRow(feature)

del cursor
```

Is there a simpler way to create a shapefile using python without adding a field for all 75 columns in the .CSV file? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply select just the columns you need; you are not *required* to use all columns.

Use the [`csv` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) to read the file, then just pick out the 2 values from each row:

```
import csv

cursor = arcpy.InsertCursor(pointFC)
with open('yourcsvfile.csv', 'rb') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
    for row in reader:
        point = arcpy.CreateObject("Point")
        point.X, point.Y = float(row[5]), float(row[27])  # take the 6th and 28th columns from the row
        cursor.insertRow(point)
```

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear, or I don't understand your script, but I need to have all 75 columns transfer over as fields to the new shapefile. When I  try to run your script with my variables, I get a 'RuntimeError: Point: Input value is not numeric', and I can't seem to troubleshoot it. Thank you for your help!

Comment: That was indeed not clear. I fixed the numeric issue. How are those other columns to be interpreted at all? You don't need to assign each of them to separate variables, take what you need and pass that on to the arcpy API.